# Track the created on and updated on data of features in geoserver layers

Tags: openlayers-3, arcgis, geoserver, datecreated, updatedate

In **arcgis** there is a capability of ***tracking the created and updated date*** of features in the layers.

[image]

Is it possible to handle the same thing from **geoserver** layers by any **settings** and / or **plugins**.

Comment: Have a look at geogig.org

Comment: Thanks for the replay @bartvde, Btw  *geogig.org* is used to handle the data versioning. I just want to handle the **created and updated date** on each feature.

Comment: this will only be available if your datastore keeps that information in the feature, because GeoServer has to deal with many types of datastore instead of just one.